# Chrome-App: Can I develop a chrome App for bluetooth interface and use it on different OS (Android, MAC, windows 8 etc)?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I am an embedded developer and have no clue about web apps. I make a sensor device with bluetooth 4.0. Can I have an chrome App that shall read the sensor data via bluetooth and have a duplex data transfer irrespective of operating system ? or in other words , Can I use a chrome app as an user interface to communicate to the sensor on all operating systems ?

Any suggestions and pointers are welcomed.

/Jagadeep.

Comment: Is that Bluetooth Low Energy? There was a recent discussion that it's not implemented everywhere yet.

Comment: Well, I have two devices, one with classical bluetooth and a new device with Bluetooth Low Power (BLP). I will be happy if I can connect either of them to a web app. Currently, I use a desktop software for UI with command-reply structure, but I am not able to use the software in all operating system and hand held device. I am looking for a solution to write once and use on all device and chrome app is just perfect for my requirement. Please let me know if this is possible ?

Comment: Classical bluetooth should work; see the docs at https://developer.chrome.com/apps/bluetooth But let someone else more experienced to answer, I haven't worked with that. Edit: also this guide: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_bluetooth

Comment: Thank you Xan, I hope someone shall provide more information.